# Problem with Getting List of Document/Collection from Directory

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I add data to collection/document as "/first/second/third/..."

For Example, **"/first/second/third/*thirdONE*"** then **"/first/second/third/*thirdTWO*"** then **"/first/second/third/*thirdTHREE*"**

then I **cannot** get list of entries inside "/first/second/third/" 
But when I add entries from Firebase Console **manually**, It works!
And, When I add an entry from the app it appears on firebase console as *italic* but when I do it manually it appears normal...!

```
val newEntry: String = "first/" +
                "second/" +
                "third/"
        firestoreDatabase
            .collection(newEntry)
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { querySnapshot ->
                println("*** " + querySnapshot.size())
                for (document in querySnapshot) {
                    Log.d(
                        "*** Firestore",
                        document.id + " => " + " Data == " + document.data
                    )
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                Log.w("***", "Error getting documents.", exception)
            }
```

[**Solution**]
Add Some Data to the Field Section of Document.

Comment: When a document ID is shown in the Firebase console in italics, it means that there is no document with that ID, but that there are subcollections under that ID.

Comment: I described the system behavior, and the likely explanation below. If that's not it, show the code of how you create the document in question.

Answer (score 1):

When a document ID is shown in the Firebase console in italics, it means that there is no document with that ID, but that there are subcollections under that ID. My guess is that you're creating a default document in the console (since the UI prompts you to do so), but don't create a document in code.

Comment: Yeah, I figure out seconds before your comments. It can be fixed by adding data to the field section.