# Exists not working in Firebase Security Rules

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm using the firestore emulator and exists isn't preventing calls when the document exists.

```
match /usernames/{username} {
  allow update: if false;
  allow create: if isUsernameAvailable(request.resource.data.username);

  function isUsernameAvailable(rawName) {
      let name = rawName.lower();

      return isValidMessage() &&
             isValidUsername(name) &&
             !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid));
  }
```

Here is the accepted Request:
[image: Request]

and Pre-Existing Document:

[image: Pre-Existing Document]

The document clearly exists. I've compared my code to similar code, and I don't see syntactical errors, so I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document title in the bottom right of that second screenshot is shown in italics, which means that the document does not actually exist. The ID is just shown in the Firestore console because you have subcollections with data under it.

In the fields section of the console, you'll also find a message to explain this:

> This document does not exist, it will not appear in queries or snapshots. [Learn more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/using-console#non-existent_ancestor_documents)

And since the document doesn't actually exist, calling `exist` on that path correctly returns false. If you want it to return true, you'll have to ensure that the document actually exists.

Also see:

- [Firestore DB - documents shown in italics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48137582/firestore-db-documents-shown-in-italics)
- [Parent document is being marked as "deleted" (italics) by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52826365/parent-document-is-being-marked-as-deleted-italics-by-default)
- [Problem with Getting List of Document/Collection from Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54499104/problem-with-getting-list-of-document-collection-from-directory)

Comment: Thanks for info! I've only been creating documents at it's sub-collection. I need to explicitly create the document or add empty data to it.